# SQL - String until first space

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(
    givenName IN VARCHAR2,
    givenClass IN VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 
AS
    result VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN 
    SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(json_obj) 
    INTO result 
    FROM
        (SELECT JSON_OBJECT('StudentName' VALUE s.name) json_obj
         FROM STUDENT s
         WHERE s.NAME = givenName, 
           AND s.class = givenClass);

    RETURN result;
END test;
```

The problem I am having is to make this query work for the following situation:

When the input parameter `givenName` and the table column `name` have more than one name, then only the first name i.e., first string until first space needs to be used to search.

```
Eg: givenName = Max Musterman, givenClass = 5

Student Table

Name          | Class
--------------+--------
Max Musterman | 5
Max Misterman | 5
Max Musterman | 4
```

Then the query should return Max Musterman from class 5 and Max Misterman from class 5.

I was able to build a normal SQL query with regex, but when I integrated it with the AND condition, even the normal query did not work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including the code you are using and the error you are getting and your expected output (is it rows from a query or are you expecting to return JSON or to modify the function or something else?). Please also explain what your `test` function has to do with the question? And your title says "String until first space" but you don't mention spaces in the body of the question at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` as follows:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJ)
  INTO RESULT
  FROM (
    SELECT JSON_OBJECT ( 'StudentName' VALUE S.NAME ) JSON_OBJ
      FROM STUDENT S
     -- Following line is changed
     WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(S.NAME,'^[^ ]+') = REGEXP_SUBSTR(GIVENNAME,'^[^ ]+') 
       AND S.CLASS = GIVENCLASS
);
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know we can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` this way. Good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

It may work using substring instead and using INSTR to specify which character you want to return all preceding text for... does this return the name as expected?

```
SELECT SUBSTR(StudentName, 1, instr(StudentName, ' ') - 1) AS Name1
FROM STUDENT
```